# How do I send push notification recieved

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm receiving the push notification, how can I send it to device with badge?
Just a simple one, with text title body badge.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {
    print("Push notification received:")
}
```

Swift 3 my environment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the badge number when your application is open, you can use `applicationIconBadgeNumber`. [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1622918-applicationiconbadgenumber).

If you want the badge to update when the application is closed then you will need to modify the code on your server sending the push to include the badge number.

You can take a look at answers [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843112/update-badge-counter-in-swift).