# Decrease ios badge count using push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way the server can decrease the number in the badge without actually showing the user with a notification?

Talking about a scenario where the user reads the message on the web

Comment: Yes. You can do that by sending badge number from the server in user info and setting it in the app. Use silent push notifications if you don't want  to show notifications

Comment: Can you give an example or guidance on the how to?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843112/update-badge-counter-in-swift for sending badge number from server

Comment: Another link for badge number update: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256643/update-badge-with-push-notification-while-app-in-background

Comment: For silent push notifications:  https://github.com/ole/SilentPush

Comment: All you need to get silent push notifications is by setting "content-available" to 1 in payload. That's it!.

Comment: If you want to get rid of handling notifications part and to make it easy, you can use any third party like oneSignal. But it costs you. Not recommended unlesss you have no choice

Comment: I already have push notifications in my app today.

Comment: Just without badge.... so basically by setting "content-available" and not setting alert/text that would do the trick?

Comment: Yes. It will work by setting Content-availble to 1. Which is nothing but silent push notifications

Comment: Do I need to write any special handler for this? The OS will handle that when the app is closed, right?

Comment: Yes. When you send Content-available flag to 1 in push notifications, OS will understand that it's a silent push notification and it won't show.